# How to Show ms charts with grouped series

Tags: char, mschart

I wanted to show bar charts in following way, how can i do this.

http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/alexgor/WindowsLiveWriter/DataBindingMSChartcontrol_10712/image_2.png

Comment: Have you tried anything? Read some docs? Looked at code samples (http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a chart containing multiple series. For example, there are 6 series in the picture.

You can download a sample project here: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4418